# Select only columns is not null

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem about MS SQL.

This is my table:

```
column_a    column_b    column_c    column_d
NULL        NULL        NULL        1
NULL        1           NULL        1
NULL        1           NULL        NULL
NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
```

I want to write a query that produces this output:

```
column_b    column_d
 NULL        1
 1           1
 1           NULL
 NULL        NULL
```

Comment: Simple answer - it is just impossible with SQL to produce different sets of columns based on data

Comment: is there any way to display data on datagridview only columns not null ?

Comment: No, there no such term "columns which are not null", columns are always not null. Value in particular row of column can be null

Comment: My answer below assumes your question is Select only columns that are not NULL in every row.  At least that's how I read it after looking at the output you are after.

Comment: Fred's answer is the way to go.  You need to build this dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question without questioning why you want to do it.  You can do this with dynamic SQL

```
DECLARE @sqlQuery VARCHAR(200)


SELECT @sqlQuery = 'SELECT '
IF EXISTS (SELECT column_a FROM myTable WHERE column_a IS NOT NULL)
SELECT @sqlQuery = @sqlQuery + 'column_a, '

IF EXISTS (SELECT column_b FROM myTable WHERE column_b IS NOT NULL)
SELECT @sqlQuery = @sqlQuery + 'column_b, '

IF EXISTS (SELECT column_c FROM myTable WHERE column_c IS NOT NULL)
SELECT @sqlQuery = @sqlQuery + 'column_c, '

IF EXISTS (SELECT column_d FROM myTable WHERE column_d IS NOT NULL)
SELECT @sqlQuery = @sqlQuery + 'column_d, '

SELECT @sqlQuery = SUBSTRING(@sqlQuery, 0, LEN(@sqlQuery)) + ' FROM myTable'

EXECUTE(@sqlQuery)
```

If it is possible that every column in every row could be `null` you would have to add a check that at least one column has been selected.